# Text on Angular website blurry/broken on production but not development

Tags: css, angular

I've run into an issue that I've been experiencing for a long time now and I can't figure it out for the life of me.

When I run `ng serve`, my text looks as is expected, sharp, correctly rendered, etc. Seen in the following:

- [development environment text 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SthUP.png)
- [development environment text 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qxlmk.png)

However when running `ng build`, the text becomes blurry and broken, like so:

- [production environment text 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8u0s.png)
- [production environment text 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aRuYr.png)

This is the same across all text in the app, no matter what font is used (i.e. Google fonts or system defaults like "Helvetica").

Inspecting the elements with built-in browser dev tools shows that they're the correct font, no silly CSS properties I've missed are present on my elements... The only difference in my dev and production environments is the following in `angular.json`:

```json
"production": {
  "optimization": {
    "scripts": true,
    "styles": {
      "minify": true,
      "inlineCritical": true
    },
    "fonts": false
  },
```

```json
"development": {
  "optimization": false,
```

As you see I've specifically set the fonts to not be optimised in the production build to try to mimic the lack of optimisation entirely in the dev environment. I've tried `-webkit-font-smoothing`, `text-rendering`, and any other CSS properties I can find to do with rendering and quality.

Interestingly, overlaying the two 'User Control Panel' images and taking away the "good" one leaves [these artefacts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dt214.png) - these artefacts are present on the production (lower quality) text but not the development text. I'm stumped. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Setting `inlineCritical` to `false` under `optimization` within my configuration fixed this issue for me. The description of this property is:

> Extract and inline critical CSS definitions to improve first paint time.

This includes fonts used.

```json
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "optimization": {
                "styles": {
                  "inlineCritical": false
                },
                "fonts": false
              },
```